# Duvida sobre vetor em C

Tags: c, array

Boa noite,  estou com uma duvida no código que fiz abaixo, meu professor solicitou que fossem lidos os valores nome, ra, n1,n2 e fosse exibida a media de 40 alunos, estou tentando porem quando tento executar meu programa não está calculando a media e o gets não funciona e só mostra um caractere ao invés do nome por completo

```
#include<stdio.h>  
#include<stdlib.h>                                                                                                                            

 int main(){
char nome[50];
int i=0,j=0,k=0,l=0,m=0;
 float n1[39],n2[39],ra[39],media[39];
 for (i=0;i<40;i++){
  printf("Insira o nome: ");
    gets("%s",&nome[i]);
   }
for (j=0;j<40;j++){
printf("Insira o RA: ");
    scanf("%d",&ra[j]);
}
for (k=0;k<40;k++){ 
    printf("Informe a primeira nota do %d aluno",k+1);
    scanf("%d",&n1[k]);
}
for (l=0;l<40;l++){
    printf("Informe a segunda nota do %d:  ",l+1);
    scanf("%d",&n2[l]);
}
for (m=0;m<40;m++){
    media[39] = (n1[k] * n2[l])/2;
    printf("o aluno %s ra numero:%d teve a media %d 
",nome[i],ra[j],media[m]);   
        }
}    
 }
```

Comment: Tente utilizar assim: `gets(nome[i])`

Answer (score 0):

Vamos lá achei varios erros no seu código e coloquei comentários explicando, mas basicamente você estava executando muitos for sem precisar, estava usando %d para float e isso usa %f, e estava tentando pegar nome em vetor precisa ser matriz, segue o código comentado e resumido, E outra não se esqueça de colocar o return 0 no final ou então colocar void dentro do parametro main assim int main(void).

```
#include<stdio.h>  
#include<stdlib.h>                                                                                                                            
#include<string.h>
 int main(){

//Quando se é string crie matriz como nome e ra terá de ter 2 o primeiro para o tamanho e o sugundo para posição
//Ra não precisa ser float
char nome[50][50],ra[40][40];

//Não necessita 5 for crie só 2
int i=0,m=0;
//Não de tamanho exato para vetores utilize sempre mais
 float n1[40],n2[40],media[40];
 for(i=0;i<40;i++){
    printf("Insira o nome: ");
    //Troquei gets por scanf com %s que significa que irá pegar uma string
    scanf("%s",nome[i]);
    printf("Insira o RA: ");
    scanf("%s",ra[i]);
    printf("Informe a primeira nota do %d aluno",i+1);
    //Seu maior erro está aqui, quando vai pegar float use %f e não %d, %d é para inteiro
    scanf("%f",&n1[i]);
    printf("Informe a segunda nota do %d:  ",i+1);
    scanf("%f",&n2[i]);
   }

    for(m=0;m<40;m++){
    media[m] = (n1[m] + n2[m])/2;
    printf("o aluno %s ra numero: %s teve a media %f",nome[m],ra[m],media[m]);   
        }

   return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A minha resposta é uma alternativa de solução ao programa que já tem corrigindo simultaneamente os problemas que o Anderson Henrique já tinha apontado.

E porque não utilizar estruturas? Se todos os vetores que está a utilizar referem informações que cada aluno tem, então pode-se criar uma estrutura que engloba a informação de cada um (à semelhança das classes em linguagens de mais alto nível).

Para as informações que tem no seu programa a estrutura ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
struct Aluno {
    char nome[50];
    float n1;
    float n2;
    float ra;
    float media;
};
```

Em que neste caso fica tudo organizado. E no main em vez de criar `5` vetores passa a criar `1` vetor de `Aluno` com `40` elementos na mesma, desta forma:

```
int main(){
    ...
    Aluno alunos[40]; //criar um vetor de 40 alunos
```

Então conjugando isto com o resto da lógica que já tem ficaria assim:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Aluno {
    char nome[50];
    float n1;
    float n2;
    float ra;
    float media;
};

typedef struct Aluno Aluno; //criar um outro nome para o tipo da estrutura para simplificar

int main(){

    int i;

    Aluno alunos[40]; //criar um vetor de 40 alunos

    for (i=0;i<40;i++){
        printf("\nInsira o nome: ");
        scanf("%s",alunos[i].nome);
        printf("Insira o RA: ");
        scanf("%f",&alunos[i].ra);
        printf("Informe a primeira nota do %d aluno: ",i+1);
        scanf("%f",&alunos[i].n1);
        printf("Informe a segunda nota do %d aluno: ",i+1);
        scanf("%f",&alunos[i].n2);
        alunos[i].media = (alunos[i].n1 + alunos[i].n2)/2; //media tem de ser com soma e não multiplicação
        printf("o aluno %s ra numero:%.2f teve a media %.2f",alunos[i].nome,alunos[i].ra,alunos[i].media);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Desta forma cada vez que pretende aceder a um aluno tem de especificar a posição e o campo da estrutura, ex:

```
alunos[2].nome
```

Que acede ao campo `nome` do aluno na posição 2. Isto será válido tanto para escrita (`printf`) como para leitura(`scanf`), com a diferença do `&` para o `scanf` sempre que o campo não é já um ponteiro.